# How to specify Xcode version in Fastlane?

Tags: ios

Now I am specify the Xcode version in Fastlane file like this:

```
lane :beta do
    xcversion(version: "12.3")
    xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode_12.3.app"
    xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_12.3.app
    if is_ci
      create_keychain(
        name: ENV['MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME'],
        password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
        default_keychain: true,
        unlock: true,
        timeout: 3600,
        lock_when_sleeps: false
      )
    end
end
```

but it shows this error:

```
Run cd ./ios && bundle exec fastlane beta
+-----------------------+---------+--------+
|               Used plugins               |
+-----------------------+---------+--------+
| Plugin                | Version | Action |
+-----------------------+---------+--------+
| fastlane-plugin-pgyer | 0.2.2   | pgyer  |
+-----------------------+---------+--------+

[02:14:34]: Sending anonymous analytics information
[02:14:34]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
[02:14:34]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
[02:14:34]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
[02:14:34]:     12:   lane :beta do
[02:14:34]:     13:     xcversion(version: "12.3")
[02:14:34]:  => 14:     xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_12.3.app
[02:14:34]:     15:     if is_ci
[02:14:34]:     16:       create_keychain(

[!] Syntax error in your Fastfile on line 14: Fastfile:14: syntax error, unexpected unary-, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
    xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_12.3.app
                 ^
Fastfile:14: unknown regexp options - Xcd
...e-select -s /Applications/Xcode_12.3.app
...                         ^~~~~~
Fastfile:14: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `end'
...elect -s /Applications/Xcode_12.3.app
...                            ^~~
Fastfile:14: unexpected fraction part after numeric literal
...ect -s /Applications/Xcode_12.3.app
...                             ^~
Fastfile:46: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

What should I do to specify the version of Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is enough:

`xcversion(version: "12.3")`

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/xcversion/):

> Finds and selects a version of an installed Xcode (...)

So the `xcode-select` instruction is not needed.
Regarding `xcode_select`, not sure if it even exists.

Comment: You could specify it as Lopes says but I would rather do it with a `.xcode-version` file.
From the documentation:

    You can either manually provide a specific version using version: or you make use of the .xcode-version file.

Answer (score 5):

**2023 Update**

As of [release 2.211.0 of Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.211.0), both the xcversion and xcode-install lanes have been depecrated and replaced with [xcodes](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/xcodes).

There are now two ways to set an Xcode version for a fastlane execution (without affecting the system selection and requiring sudo permission).

1. Providing the full path to an executable with the [xcode_select](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/xcode_select) action:

```rb
xcode_select("/Applications/Xcode-14.1.app")
```

2. Providing a version to match with the new [xcodes](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/xcodes) action:

```rb
xcodes(version: "14.1", select_for_current_build_only: true)
```

Note that if you opt for **option 2**, you will need to install the [xcodes CLI](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/xcodes) in the system you are executing your fastlane action from.